# Can I read the Request.Body twice in net core?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, request

I have a post method which is called by a third-party.  To verify it is them they are encrypting the body and adding it as a header. So I can do the same and check valid.

I was hoping to do this as some kind of attribute so I can re-use it automatically in the whole controller, so I have:

```
public class Verify : ActionFilter, IAsyncAuthorizationFilter 
{
  public async Task OnAuthorizationAsync(AuthorizationFilterContext context)
  {
    var signature = context.HttpContext.Request.Headers["x-signature"];
    var requestBody = await new StreamReader(context.HttpContext.Request.Body).ReadToEndAsync();
    var key = "my-secure-key";

    if (EncryptTheBody(requestBody, key) != signature) 
    {
      // not valid
      context.Result = new UnauthorizedResult();
    }
    context.HttpContext.Request.Body.Position = 0;  //added this - but doesn't work
  }
}
```

Works good.
Except I need to get the body later on in the controller action

```
[HttpPost]
[Verify]
public Task Post(MyModel model){  
  // model is all null.  
}
```

Any ideas?  Solutions? Better approaches?

I could copy/paste everything above into the controller, delete the attribute, then just use the string'd body twice, but would like to avoid.

Comment: Even if you can, you risk the app on an undocumented implementation. Why not copy the body to a new stream? So that everything are under your control.

Comment: It depends what type of `Stream` that `Body` property refers to. Check the `CanSeek` property of that object. If that is `true` then you can reset the stream position to the start and it can be read again. If that property is `false`, which I suspect will be the case, then the stream position cannot be reset so it cannot be read again.

Comment: By the way, it might make more sense to hash the data rather than encrypt it. Maybe that's already what you're doing and you just used incorrect terminology. Have you ever seen sites that provide MD5 hashes for files downloads? That's so that you can check that the data isn't corrupt after downloading the file. You can use an MD5 has in the same way to validate your request body.

Comment: Ah, I just notice3d that you are already trying to set the `position`` back to zero. If that's not working then `CanSeek` must be `false` so you're out of luck. For `Streams` backed by files or memory, random access is not a problem. If the data is coming over the network though, once it is delivered once then that's it. The sender is not going to randomly send it again.

Comment: I don't know what version you are using but. If you want to read twice RequestBody in asp.net core you need to enable `context.HttpContext.Request.EnableBuffering()`

Answer (score 1):

You can do that by using Request buffering, but you have to enable the buffering **before** the request data is read for the first time, including ASP.NET's native reading of the request data. By the time you get into your controller the Request.Body has already been read.

To do this you have hook up a custom middleware handler that has to run before the ASP.NET Controller's are added (in program.cs/startup.cs):

```cs
app.Use(async (context, next) =>
{
     context.Request.EnableBuffering();
     await next();
}
```

If you need to read the buffer before your controller code you can use something like this in that same handler:

```cs
app.Use(async (context, next) =>
{
    if (context.Request.Method == "POST" || context.Request.Method == "PUT")
    {
        string bodyString = null;
        
        // this is early enough in the pipeline
        context.Request.EnableBuffering();
        
         using var reader = new StreamReader(context.Request.Body,
                                 Encoding.UTF8,
                                 detectEncodingFromByteOrderMarks: false,
                                 leaveOpen: true /* important! */);
                                     
         try
         {
             bodyString = await reader.ReadToEndAsync();

             // reset the stream to start position
             if (context.Request.Body.CanSeek)
               context.Request.Body.Position = 0;          
         }
         catch(Exception)
         {
             bodyString = null;
         }
                
        // ... do something with the capture data
    }
    
    await next();    
}
```

If you need to do your capture **after** ASP.NET has processed the request data, you can manually reset the stream position and then do the reading:

```cs
[HttpPost]
[Verify]
public async Task<object> Post(MyModel model){  
{   
     // make sure that the stream is readable!
     if (context.Request.Body.CanSeek) 
     {
          Context.HttpContext.Request.Body.Position = 0;
          // ...  READ THE STREAM here as above
     )
}
```

For more detailed information [see this blog post](https://weblog.west-wind.com/posts/2024/Feb/20/Reading-Raw-ASPNET-RequestBody-Multiple-Times).